# Multiple Consumer groups

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

How to add multiple values in the spring.kafka.consumer.group-id = test-consumer-group, test-consumer-group1 in the application.properties file in spring boot?

I have tried this but it's not working!
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id = test-consumer-group\ test-consumer-group1

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know about kafka but i know about spring boot. If group-id is a Collection, you can do like this:

```
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id[0]= test-consumer-group
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id[1]= test-consumer-group1
```

Comment: No the group id is not collection.  Actually I have two consumer groups and I need to add the consumer group ids in the application.properties file, so that each consumer can receive the message from sender.

Comment: you can simple add with 'space', capture as String and then, split by space.

Comment: I need to add 
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id = group1 group2
in the application.properties file in spring boot application.

I am trying to create two different consumer groups and calling the customer one by one in @KafkaListner by spliting the the ids by space. But doing this creates a single consumer with consumer id as 'group1 group2'.